# Getting Intent of type Image Confusion

Tags: android, android-intent

I am currently learning Android and came across with this:

```
    if (intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) {
    // Handle intents with image data ...
    } else if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
    // Handle intents with text ...
```

I don't understand why there is `intent.getType().indexOf("image/")!=-1`, As far as I understand it's being used to know that if the intent contains data of type Image (Correct me if wrong). but why not its used like it is used with type `"text/plain"`. Why its using `indexOf` and why its checked against `-1`.

Pardon, if the question doesn't makes sense after all. But, as I said I am learning and didn't found much information of it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that whoever wrote the code is using this to try to match anything starting with `image/`. Using `startsWith()` would be simpler and more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

getType will return a mimetype such as "image/png" "text/plain" "application/json" etc.

The indexOf call is to see if the string "image/" exists somewhere in the mimetype - or more practically if the type is an image. The author does not care if it is a jepg ("image/jpeg") or a png ("imgage/png") etc. just that it is an image.

The check against -1 is because if the "image/" substring is *not* found, that will be the return value.

if it is not an image, they are checking to see if it is plain text.

This is probably not the cleanest way to achieve this, but it gets the job done.